# Retrieving IndexPath of UITableView cell with UIButton when touched

Tags: swift, uibutton, tableview

I'm struggling how to retrieve the indexPath of a UITableViewCell when the button in the cell is tapped. I'm using the typical delegate code for the button. I've googled and experimented with this but I can't get it. Here is my Custom Tableview cell code:

```
import UIKit

protocol MainTableViewCellDelegate {
    func tappedReport(id: String)
}

class MainTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postLabel: UILabel!

    var postItem: PostData!
    var delegate: MainTableViewCellDelegate?

    func setPost(post: PostData) {
        postItem = post
        let ourPost = postItem.postId
        print(ourPost)
    }

    @IBAction func reportButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.tappedReport(id: postItem.postId)
        //print("Reported post ID: \(postItem.postId)")
    }
}

// View controller/ cellforRowat


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MainTableViewCell
        cell.postLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].message
        cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cell.userLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].username

        cell.delegate = self
        cell.getIndexPath()
}

extension ViewController: MainTableViewCellDelegate {
    func tappedReport(id: String) {

        print("Hi")
        AlertController.showAlert(inViewController: self, title: "Report", message: "Report button tapped.")
    }
}
```

And ideas?

Comment: What's happening when you tap the button in a cell? Are you getting an error or behavior that you don't want? It seems that if you're trying identify the cell that was tapped then using the standard `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ` would be the simplest way to do it. You could then easily get at the properties of the button inside of it to send to your `tappedReport` method.

Comment: Actually Kane Cheshire’s answer worked, but for some reason it keeps catching nil when I tap the button. If it take the ‘postItem.postId’ out, and replace it with something random(“hi”) then it works fine. I also am getting the indexPath now so I think I will be able to find the .postId in a different way.

Comment: Unrelated, but you may want to define your protocol to be a `class` protocol (e.g. `protocol MainTableViewCellDelegate: class { ... }`) and the define your `delegate` to be `weak` (e.g. `weak var delegate: MainTableViewCellDelegate?`). In the absence of that, you’ll have a strong reference cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the cell back as part of the delegate call, you can ask the table view for the index path of it.

Define the delegate protocol:

```
protocol MainTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func cell(_ cell: MainTableViewCell, didTapReport reportID: String)
}
```

In your cell, define the handler for the report button being tapped and inform the delegate:

```
@IBAction func reportButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.cell(self, didTapReport: postItem.postID)
}
```

Then in the view controller (which is your cell's delegate according to your code):

```
func cell(_ cell: MainTableViewCell, didTapReport reportID: String) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    // Do something with the index path
}
```

Because there might not be an index path for that cell (you can pass any cell into that argument) the return type is optional, so you’ll have to check that `indexPath` is not `nil` before using it. So you might need to do something like

`guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but where does 'delegate?.cell(self, didTapReport: postItem.postID)' go?

Comment: @JackDerbis That's the cell calling its delegate. It goes in your cell's `reportButton` method in place of the current delegate call.

Comment: @JackDerbis Please don't forget, if an answer has solved your question you should accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. This lets people know a solution has been found.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option without using delegates or IB actions in UITableViewCell subclasses. You can add this method as UIView extension

```
extension UIView {

    func superview<T: UIView>(of viewType: T.Type) -> T? {
        if superview == nil {
            return nil
        }

        if let view = superview as? T {
            return view
        }

        return superview?.superview(of: viewType)
    }
}
```

and use it in view controller like this

```
@IBAction func actionTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard
        let cell = sender.superview(of: YourCustomCell.self),
        let row = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row
    else {
        return
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create property of indexpath inside you cell and in cellForRow method set indexpath of cell.

Than on button tap just use self.indexPath.

May be this will fix your issue

Comment: Do not do this. This solution fails in table views where rows can be added, deleted, or moved.